# Android can't switch input fields

Tags: android, android-layout

In my android app, I've realized that anytime I setup a screen with multiple EditTexts, I am not able to select any EditText other than the last one on the screen.  If I click on other EditTexts, the last one is still selected.  On this screen, I have an EditText and some radio buttons.  I can select any of these with no problem.  The Third Radio button, when selected, changes the visibility of some hidden EditTexts to Visible.  Once these other 4 fields are visible I try to select one.  Regardless of which one I select, the keyboard opens up for the 4th input field, and I cannot switch the focus to anything else, including the radio buttons.  This has happened on other screens with multiple EditTexts that are laid out in xml files.

I have screens with multiple EditTexts where everything works fine, however, it only works fine when I programatically add EditTexts via Java.

If someone can explain why this is happening, it would be a great help.

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ask_question"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
tools:context=".AskQuestionActivity">

<TextView android:text="What's on your mind? "
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/questionLineOne"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingTop="45dp" />


<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/questionType"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="80dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Yes/No"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Like/Dislike"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Custom"/>

</RadioGroup>


<EditText android:id="@+id/input1"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="145dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/input2"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="195dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/input3"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="245dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<EditText android:id="@+id/input4"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="295dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="175dp"
    android:onClick="cancel"/>

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="Poll!"
    android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:onClick="saveQuestion"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're experiencing but, `android:visibility="gone"` will certainly make it so you can't select them

Comment: You know if you used a LinearLayout, you wouldn't need to increment the top padding for each view

Comment: I have java code that changes the visibility when a the third radio button is clicked.

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a bug with the emulator...

Comment: having same issue but solved by debugging code

Comment: was your issue related to the focus?

Comment: or what was the problem in your case?